# Parallelization of multi-step pipeline

Tags: java, spring-boot, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have troubles with making readable and highly parallelized pipeline in Java.

Background: I have ~10 step pipeline. Some steps call libraries, that do their own locking and admission controls (esp. for remote calls). I'd like to maximize the parallelism while preserving readability.

My implementation does it using Java streams:

```
return Stream
  .of("some input")
  .parallel()
  .map(x -> step1(param, x))
  .flatMap(Util2::step2)
  .map(Util3::step3)
  .flatMap(Util4::step4)
  .flatMap(Util5::step5)
  .map(x -> step6(x, somethingElse))
  // few more steps
  .toList();
```

I really like the way this is expressed and it would probably work as expected if it didn't contain admission controls on the library level. Maybe because of that, it seems it's not utilizing CPU to the fullest and whole pipeline is really slow.

My load average is around 0.6 when running, so my system has performance to do more. I know `step1` itself is fast, when I shorten the pipeline to do just that. Even then, I can see only first element of `step1` to go to `step2` for pretty long time - I guess it has to complete pipeline for that element before starting with the next one. Maybe it goes "DFS".

What I also tried:

```
// Shows still the same thread confirming my suspicion.
System.out.println("We're in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

And I also tried using a different executor, but it seems it also has no effects whatsoever, also confirmed by me getting thread names:

```
var executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
var maybeResult = executor.submit(() -> Stream
  .of("some input")
  .parallel()
  .map(x -> step1(param, x))
  .flatMap(Util2::step2)
  ... and so on);
return maybeResult.get();
```

I considered running custom thread for each step; one would also flatten the lists and so on. But it's much less readable when I just start writing that. And it's a lot of work.

I also tried using Flux from project reactor and the result seems to be the same.

Idea profiler shows me CPU usage (as far as I know/see) and thus is useless.

To exclude some issues in my setup:
I am running on 8 core CPU, running bare-metal on Ubuntu. Java program is directly executed from Idea, running Java Correto 17. And I'm running it as `@ShellMethod` from Spring Boot currently.
I try to keep my settings as default as possible, but I have pretty large system, so I cannot isolate it properly.
Suggesting debugging tools to find out what's blocking it, other frameworks or design is fine, I only cannot rewrite all the APIs.